# Facet plot in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, visualization, powerbi-desktop, vega, deneb

Is there a way to create facet plot in power bi ? Many thanks in advance.

[image: Similar to this]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some core visuals support faceting (known as small multiples) but scatter chart is not one of them. This type of chart faceting can only be done with 3rd party visuals. I highly recommend Deneb which is free and certified.

https://deneb-viz.github.io/

https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/

[image]